# Hardware virtualization error found during kali linux installation

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install Kali Linux in Oracle Virtual Box. During installation i`m geeting 2 problems,

1. I am not getting Debian 64bit at version tab though my laptop is 64 bit. I am getting only Debian 32 bit.
2. I am getting bellow error and OK button is disabled.

"The Hardware virtualization is enabled in the Acceleration Section of the System page although it is not supported by the host system. It should be disabled in order to start the virtual system."

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Check your BIOS. Make sure virtualization technologies are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Check if CPU virtualization extensions are enabled in your BIOS. Virtualbox refuses to run 64-bit machines without those extensions.